# Android - How can I create a ScrollView with many Layouts inside it?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create this following screen layout for my movie app:

[image: Movie App]

I created this layout to accomplish it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ButtonPanel"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/id_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="3">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/identification_label"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:text="Movie Identification"
                        android:textColor="@color/BaseColor_1"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/edit_identification"
                        style="@style/IconButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:contentDescription="TODO"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_icon"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.55"

                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/identification_label"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="226dp" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/help_button"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_help"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

                        style="@style/IconButton" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/sample_name_label"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
                        android:text="Movie Name"
                        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                        android:textColor="@color/BaseColor_1"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/sample_description_label"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
                        android:text="Movie Description"
                        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                        android:textColor="@color/BaseColor_1"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sample_name_label" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/sample_show_content_description"
                        style="@style/IconButton"
                        android:layout_width="18dp"
                        android:layout_height="18dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/btn_reveal_sample_description"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/sample_description_label"

                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/sample_description_label" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/sample_description_text"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
                        android:maxLines="0"
                        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                        android:textColor="@color/BaseColor_1"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sample_description_label" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/identification_data_divider"

                    style="@style/Divider" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/location_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/id_layout">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/location_label"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:text="Other Information"
                        android:textColor="@color/BaseColor_1"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/diretor_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
                    android:text="Director Name"
                    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                    android:textColor="@color/BaseColor_1"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
                    android:text="Main actor"
                    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                    android:textColor="@color/BaseColor_1"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/b"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
                    android:text="Movie Genre"
                    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                    android:textColor="@color/BaseColor_1"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/f"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
                    android:text="Critics rating"
                    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                    android:textColor="@color/BaseColor_1"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <View style="@style/Divider" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/picture_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/location_layout"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/picture_label"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:text="@string/sample_images_label"
                        android:textColor="@color/BaseColor_1"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/first_picture"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/outcrop_placeholder" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/second_picture"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/outcrop_placeholder" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/third_picture"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/outcrop_placeholder" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/ButtonPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@color/BaseColor_4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/delete_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_delete"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/confirm_button"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.004"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"

            style="@style/IconButton" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/confirm_button"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
            android:text="@string/confirm_button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

            style="@style/RoundedCornersMaterialButton" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you can see I have to set manually the images' `layout_height`, but I would like to get the best proportion for the pictures (adjust the images 15dp on top of the bottom toolbar). I have tried to use `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf` in the `LinearLayout` that contains these pictures, but when I click on the collpasible and the description is shown I need to scroll through the screen to see the pictures, but using `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf` the images simply disappear.

I know that `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf` should not be used in this case, but is there any other way to change the `layout_height` of my pictures to `wrap_content` and get the best size for them when I have to scroll down?

Basically, I want another option (besides `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf`) that will adjust the images 15dp on top of the bottom toolbar when I am scrolling down.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Thanks!

Comment: "the best proporsition for the pictures" What does that mean? "is there any other way to change the layout_height of my pictures to wrap_content?" Why is it a problem to change it to wrap_content? "I have tried to use app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf" If you want to use this attribute you have to replace the LinearLayout with a ConstraintLayout.

Comment: Best proportion means that the height would adapt to the screen available, for example when I scroll down I want to keep it 15dp on top of the bottom toolbar, but now when I set the height manually I am not able to do it. I cannot use wrap_content because then the image disappears from my screen... I don't want to change to ConstraintLayout, I want another option that will adjust the images 15dp on top of the bottom toolbar.